# Liquibase partially rolling back a changeset

Tags: liquibase, rollback, changeset

I have a simple liquibase changeset (below) which I'm trying to test.

It is the second changelog to be run after app startup.

I have coded a deliberate error where I try to create column "NEW_2" twice to force a rollback of all entries in changeset: ADD_COL_2

However even though the rollback file is generated AND I see:

INFO 4/13/16 12:17 AM: liquibase: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-multi-set-then-rollback.xml: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-multi-set-then-rollback.xml::ADD_COL_2::USER1: Rolling Back Changeset:classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-multi-set-then-rollback.xml::ADD_COL_2::USER1

INFO 4/13/16 12:17 AM: liquibase: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-multi-set-then-rollback.xml: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-multi-set-then-rollback.xml::ADD_COL_1::USER1: Rolling Back Changeset:classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-multi-set-then-rollback.xml::ADD_COL_1::USER1

In the logs, only the NEW_4 & NEW_5 column create is rolled back.

The ADD_COL_2 changelog does NOT appear in DATABASECHANGELOG.

ADD_COL_1 changelog does apppear in DATABASECHANGELOG.

To test if the rollback worked, I execute a Native query against TABLE_1 and I can see values for NEW_1,2.. I would only expect to see NEW_1 as NEW_2 is part of the failed changeset?

If I also query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES I see NEW_1 and NEW_2.

I have tried combinations of no rollback tag, explicit rollback tags for each statement, group tags, all to no avail.
I have tried to move the Tag to its own changeset.

To me what seems to be happening is that all changes up to the failed command are not rolled back.

Do I need to  manually call something ? Do I need to manually execute the rollback file, am I misunderstanding how liquibase works and it isn't automatic on failure???

I'm genuinely at my wits end here, I (think) I've run about every combination possible.. I hoping I'm doing something stupid!

Any help is immeasurably appreciated !!

I am using Spring version 4.1.7, Liquibase 3.4.2 and running the test in Junit.

Changeset: problem ADD_COL_2 is not fully rolled back, NEW_2 column remains in TABLE_1

```
    <changeSet id="ADD_COL_1" author="USER1" failOnError="true">
    <comment>Add column NEW_1 to TABLE_1</comment>
    <tagDatabase tag="ADD_COL_1"/>
    <addColumn tableName="TABLE_1">
        <column name="NEW_1" type="varchar(10)" value="NEW_1"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="ADD_COL_2" author="USER1" failOnError="true">
    <tagDatabase tag="ADD_COL_2"/>
    <comment>Add column NEW_2 to TABLE_1</comment>
    <addColumn tableName="TABLE_1">
        <column name="NEW_2" type="varchar(10)" value="NEW_2"/>
    </addColumn>

    <comment>Add column NEW_3 to TABLE_1</comment>
    <addColumn tableName="TABLE_1">
        <column name="NEW_2" type="varchar(10)" value="NEW_3"/>
    </addColumn>

    <comment>Add column NEW_4 to TABLE_1</comment>
    <addColumn tableName="TABLE_1">
        <column name="NEW_4" type="varchar(10)"/>
    </addColumn>

    <comment>Add column NEW_5 to TABLE_1</comment>
    <addColumn tableName="TABLE_1">
        <column name="NEW_5" type="varchar(10)"/>
    </addColumn>

    <rollback>
        <dropColumn tableName="TABLE_1" columnName="NEW_2"/>
        <dropColumn tableName="TABLE_1" columnName="NEW_3"/>
        <dropColumn tableName="TABLE_1" columnName="NEW_4"/>
        <dropColumn tableName="TABLE_1" columnName="NEW_5"/>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

**************** ADDITIONAL INFO ****************

Updates are run internally in my app, no external liquibase commands are run.

My service extends SpringLiquibase and is executed automatically once the properties are set.

Answer (score 3):

Liquibase doen't run any `<rollback>` sections until you ask it to do it (using liquibase command). It executes each changeset in transaction and if it fails it tries to rollback this transaction using database transactions engine (that has some limitations, for example, if you add a column A in MySQL and after it fail to add column B in the same transaction, than A is not rolled back because MySql do commit after DDL statements).

Comment: So in the case above, my script failed half way through. Is there a liquibase command/method I need to execute **inside** my code to run   the rollback ? And just to confirm, my assumption that all changes will automaically get rollback is incorrect?

Comment: If you add 5 columns in a single changeset and 2nd column fails liquibase tries to rollback the whole changeset, but, as I said, mysql will not rollback already added columns because they are commited. Have a look at this page: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html to see how to use rollback in Liquibase. But I think that rollback will also fail in your case because it will try to drop columns, that are not created yet. To avoid this issue you should have each creation of the column in separate changeset (also for rollback for addColumn could be auto-generated by Liquibase).

Comment: Thanks for the info, will give it a try.

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://www.liquibase.org/bestpractices.html It contains some useful suggestions about changelogs.

Comment: apologies dbf, I haven't had a chance to try this out yet as other things have risen in priority, ill mark this question once I get a chance to fully try your suggestions.